# Does every quadratic matrix define an endomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering: does every quadratic matrix define an endomorphism?

Sure the map defined by the quadratic matrix goes from a vector space of $n$ dimensions to a vector space of $n$ dimensions. But why are these vector spaces necessarily the same?

Comment: Editing note: while making grammar fixes, I preserved the use of "quadratic matrix". Posters have figured out is supposed to mean "square matrix", but it seems to make sense to leave it alone for the poster's benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a matter of terminology, one speaks of a *square* matrix.

And then, an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over the field $F$ can be chosen to represent several things.

You may take two vector spaces $V, W$ of the same dimension over the same field $F$, choose bases $(e_i)$ of $V$ and $(f_i)$ of $W$, and then a matrix $A$ may be taken to represent an arbitrary $F$-linear map $V \mapsto W$ with respect to those bases.

If you choose $V = W$ and $e_i= f_i$, then $A$ may be taken to represent an endomorphism of $V$ with respect to the chosen basis.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Then an endomorphism is not already given by a square matrix, but also presupposes the same basis in the two vectorspaces.

Comment: There are problems for which you might want different bases, but if you want to compose endomorphisms by multiplying matrices, you'd better use just one basis.

Answer (score 1):

Well, essentially every $n$-dimensional vector space over the same field is the same (as vector fields), so the answer would be yes.